# Using page-id-{ID} from body_class() in local dev, versus live staging

Tags: theme-development, jquery, css, local-installation

Not sure this is a question suitable for this forum, but I'll try:

I think it is pretty convenient targeting elements in css/jQuery for a specific page by using the page-id-{ID} generated by body_class() in a template.

But this gets problematic when developing on a local dev machine and then transfering to a staging server for your customer where the page id's is not the same.

How do you handle this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How many different _style sets_ do you (want to) have? I consider this neither convenient nor applicable. But maybe I got you wrong. Do you really have for each of a lot of pages a separate style for certain elements? Where are these elements located?

Comment: Not different style sets. What I mean is for example if I have a div and want to set a different background-image for it depending on page, I use the page-id-{ID} in CSS.

Comment: Where is this `<div />` located? In the page content (=> dynamical)? Or in a sidebar, header, footer (=> static)? Do you want to style this differently for _some_ or for all of your pages?

Comment: Not in the content but otherwise located all over the place. And for some pages.

Comment: @tf What he want to do is something like this: create a page 'dog' with ID 3 and a page 'cat' with ID 5. Then style the background with `.page-id-3 { background: url(dog.jpg) }` `.page-id-5{ background: url(cat.png) }`

Comment: Yes, thats what I do and works well I think. But I'm not a very exp developer and localhost vs staging server poses problems

Comment: Thanks @Ralf912, I got that. :) That's why I asked **how and where** this is to be used. If there are only a few of these elements, I'd either give each of them an ID or use a _dynamic stylesheet_. If there is one (or more) element(s) for each page, I'd do this by using jQuery/PHP - most probably in combination with CSS (static or dynnamic) but not with CSS alone. But I guess, I shouldn't think too much and just provide what was asked for. ;)

Comment: By dynamic stylesheet you mean like LESS?

Comment: Don't know why this didn't get asked before, why are the ids different at all?  Just transfer the full install to the staging server and run a find/replace script.  If you need to only demo a couple pages to a client, it's a matter of seconds to change the styles for those two pages if you want to create them in a different WP install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use slugs instead of IDs.

Taken from the Starkers theme (add it to your functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_to_body_class' );

    function add_slug_to_body_class( $classes ) {
        global $post;

        if( is_home() ) {           
            $key = array_search( 'blog', $classes );
            if($key > -1) {
                unset( $classes[$key] );
            };
        } elseif( is_page() ) {
            $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $post->post_name );
        } elseif(is_singular()) {
            $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $post->post_name );
        };

        return $classes;
    }
```

Comment: Hm, let me think about this for a while. Not a too exp dev you see.. Thanks

Comment: This is of course what I want. Sorry for being late. Thanks!

Comment: Also these:

http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-function-to-get-postpage-slug and http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-url-slugs-as-body-classes/